# Unable to reference json file in Data attribute but array list data works

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, cal-heatmap

I am incorporating cal-heatmap in my asp.net website and all works fine as long as i am referencing data through an array, initialized as variable above the init method, however things stop showing up as soon as i create new text file in visual studio and rename it as datas-years.json and reference it in 'data' attribute, please help me ?

below is the working code, manually entered data in array and referencing 
[image]

```
var cal = new CalHeatMap();
var data = { "1420498800": 20, "1420585200": 40, "1420671600": 60, "1420758000": 1, "1421103600": 2, "1421190000": 90, "1421276400": 1, "1421362800": 1, "1421622000": 1, "1421708400": 1, "1422226800": 1, "1422313200": 1, "1422399600": 2, "1422486000": 1, "1422572400": 1, "1423695600": 3, "1424127600": 2, "1424214000": 1, "1424300400": 3, "1424386800": 1, "1424646000": 2, "1424732400": 1, "1424818800": 2, "1424905200": 2, "1424991600": 1, "1425337200": 1, "1425855600": 4, "1426201200": 2, "1426460400": 2, "1426546800": 1, "1426633200": 2, "1426719600": 1, "1426806000": 1, "1427065200": 1, "1427151600": 1, "1427238000": 2, "1427324400": 1, "1427670000": 2, "1428361200": 2, "1428447600": 2, "1428534000": 3, "1428620400": 3, "1428966000": 2, "1429138800": 2, "1429225200": 1, "1429484400": 2, "1429570800": 1, "1429657200": 2, "1429743600": 2, "1429830000": 3 };

cal.init({
    data: data,
    itemName: ["volunteer", "volunteers"],
    start: new Date(2015, 0, 1, 1),
    domain: "month",
    subDomain: "day",
    cellSize: 15,
    subDomainTextFormat: "%d",
    range: 12,
    legend: [20, 40, 60, 80],


});
```

below is the referencing through separate file, all under visual studio

[image: not working]

```
var cal = new CalHeatMap();

cal.init({

    datatype:JSON,
    data: "datas-years.json",
    itemName: ["volunteer", "volunteers"],
    start: new Date(2015, 0, 1, 1),
    domain: "month",
    subDomain: "day",
    cellSize: 15,
    subDomainTextFormat: "%d",
    range: 12,
    //highlight: new Date(2016, 1, 15),
    legend: [20, 40, 60, 80],


});
```

I also would like to know what is the best way to convert the date to seconds format, when i impliment it in live, should i ensure that it is added in seconds format to json file or it can be just like 2/26/2015 ? and then convert it into seconds while borrowing from json file ? Please guide me, thank you

**EDIT:**

Data in the datas-years.json file in directory

[{
"1420498800":20,
"1420585200":40,
"1420671600":80,
"1421708400": 1, 
"1422226800": 1, 
"1422313200": 1, 
"1422399600": 2, 
"1422486000": 1
}]

Comment: Have you checked if your JSON is valid or not? Do you see any error message in the console/network tab while fetching JSON? And is your JSON file residing in the same directory as the calling file? Without these info it'll be difficult to draw a conclusion.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian hi, i did nothing but just copy pasted the same working data samples to the new file in the same directory. content of datas-years.json has been updated in the question now, please check and let me know if there is any mistake

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors? Can you post the link from where you are using this code? Will be easy to comprehend what is going on. Your JSON seems fine.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian Thank you for the time , here is the project on github, i am taking from this and doing it, when i take the values in array and assign it to attribute data it works fine but why it is not taking the file path is the worrying aspect, https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap

Comment: Hi, can you try passing the entire path like `http://localhost/path-to-your-dir/datas-years.json`. May be the plugin is not able to access the file. Also remove all other extra options until you get the data to work. Will be easy to debug. You can also remove the `datatype: "json"` as it is set by default in the plugin. Open your chrome console and check if you see any error when requesting the json file.

Comment: @ThomasSebastian I can see that the console showing json file has not been loaded...even if i change the file reference path like you said, still the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108184/discussion-between-thomas-sebastian-and-santhoshkumar-b).